# IIS Server Compilation Error Cs0433

Tags: asp.net, iis

****Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. ****

CS0433: The type 'Resources.Languages' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e73e52f0\f24c7c93\App_GlobalResources.6neu9und.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e73e52f0\f24c7c93\assembly\dl3\3999189e\4bde119c_67e9cb01\App_GlobalResources.DLL'

*I got the followring Error when i upload a non compile version of my website. I have already uploaded the compile version of the website and its running without any error, How ever when i upload the non-compile version of the website then i got the above mention error.
i am using .net version 2.0. Running win2000 server.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a usual problem that we used to face before.

The simplest way to get it fixed is to navigate to the conflicting directories,delete the compiled ones from there, and then start using your website to get it recompiled again.

the second approach, REFRESH..REFRESH..REFRESH :)

Comment: I have compile and non compile version, so which directory should i delete? from the path, i have two path.

Comment: do delete both, don't worry, the one you will need will be recreated again, and your site will be working fine.